# The underlying provider failed on Open. MVC

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, connection-string

I am developing an application which consists of service, data layer(which is class library) and mvc project.
I am using EF 5. My connection string is the following:

```
add name="PicknickDBEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;
     provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
     provider connection string=&quot;
     data source=*******\SQLEXPRESS;
     initial catalog=PicknickDB;
     integrated security=True;
     User Instance=True;
     MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
     App=EntityFramework&quot;
     " providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I just copied this one from the service web.config but it is not working under the IIS. Any ideas?

PS(I know that this question appears at least a few times with good solutions but I wasn't unable to find the correct one for me.)

Comment: Can you check your entityframework version? Make sure that you are targetting the correct version of EF on your web.config file.

Comment: yep it Entity Framework  5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along these lines.

```
     <add name="LeaveMSContext"
    connectionString="Data Source=*******\SQLEXPRESS; 
    Initial Catalog=NAMEOFYOURDATABASE; Integrated Security=True;
    AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|DATABASEFILE.mdf 
    MultipleActiveResultSets=True; "
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```